# Getting a hold of elastic data within Kibana Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-6

I've been developing a ReactJS based Kibana plugin and have been trying to search my elastic search data within the plugin. Does anyone know what's the best way to approach this? I attempted to use the elastic API but I ran into cross-origin issues and felt like it wouldn't be secure editing the elastic config file to allow cross origin data. I did some looking around and found that I can possibly use the elasticsearch.js library but I haven't figured out how to implement it. In addition, I'm not sure if its usable within a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

use the example below to query Elasticsearch from the client. The request will go to Kibana's `elasticsearch` endpoint and then get routed to the Elasticsearch cluster configured by `elasticsearch.url`

`import chrome from 'ui/chrome';
const response = await fetch(chrome.addBasePath('/elasticsearch/_msearch'), {
  method: 'post',
  body: body, // body is just your elasticsearch body
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson',
    'kbn-xsrf': 'kibana',
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});`